# Loading different Content panes of dojo in a JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I have a JSP page. In that i have different Content panes(using Dojo framework). Now for a particular content pane to be displayed on page load i have set "selected= true" property true on one of the content panes(Add new activity). Now i have another content pane on which data is displayed using dojox.grid.DataGrid(pending activities). But as the page loads i get my Add new activity pane absolutely fine. but as soon as i switch on to another pane(pending activities) i get a grid but no data inside it. And when i set "selected= true" property for pending activities pane i get my data displayed correctly inside grid.  I think the problem is that my page is loading one time only. how to solve that ? Thanks..

the code for my jsp page is ::

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="MyPackage.PopulateTextbox" %>
<%@page import="MyPackage.TextboxAutocomplete" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>DojoContentPanes</title>
<style type="text/css">
   @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
   @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css";
   @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
   @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojox/grid/resources/nihiloGrid.css";

</style>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/js/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="isDebug: false, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
dojo.require('dijit.form.TextBox');
dojo.require('dijit.Tooltip');
dojo.require('dijit.form.DateTextBox');
dojo.require('dijit.form.TimeTextBox');
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require('dijit.layout.TabContainer');
dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
dojo.require('dijit.form.Button');
dojo.require('dijit.form.NumberSpinner');
dojo.require('dijit.form.Textarea');

</script>
</head>
<%
  TextboxAutocomplete obj1 = new TextboxAutocomplete();
  String arlene1 =  obj1.method();
  request.setAttribute("variable1", arlene1);
%>

<%
String temp1;
PopulateTextbox obj = new PopulateTextbox();
temp1 = obj.method();
request.setAttribute("variable", temp1); 
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.ready(function(){
var myVar = <%= request.getAttribute("variable") %>
var storedata={
            identifier:"ID",
            label:"name",
            items: myVar
    };

var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata});

    var gridStructure =[[

                      { field: "ID",
                            name: "ID_Emp",
                            width: "60%",
                            classes:"firstname"
                      },
                      {
                          field: "Names",
                          name: "Name",
                          width: "60%",
                          classes: "firstname"
                      }

                ]
          ];


     var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            id: 'grid',
            store: store,
            structure: gridStructure,
            rowSelector: '30px',
            selectionMode: "single",
            autoHeight:true},
          document.createElement('div'));

        /*append the new grid to the div*/
        dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

        /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
        grid.startup();

     // assuming our grid is stored in a variable called "myGrid":
        dojo.connect(grid, "onSelectionChanged", grid, function(){
            var items = this.selection.getSelected();

        //  do something with the selected items
            dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
                var v = this.store.getValue(item, "Names");

                function showDialog() {
                    dijit.byId("terms").show();
                }
                showDialog();
                }, this);

        });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myVar1 = <%=request.getAttribute("variable1") %>
      //var foo = (function(){

          //[];
          //arlene1 = obj.method();
      //});
      //foo();
        //arlene1 = ["Shaan","kapil","abhinav"];
    $("input#assignedbyid").autocomplete({
    source: myVar1
});
  });
  </script>

<body class="nihilo" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/14.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">

<div style="width:1000px;height:600px;">

  <!-- will host all tabs and their content panes -->
  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" id="tabContainer" style="width:1000px;height:100%;">

    <!-- content panes: title is tab name, make this tab selected -->
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Add New Activity" preload="true" selected="true">      

<div style="width:1200px;height:600px;background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/18.png');width:1200px;height:600px;">
<center><div style="border-color:black; width: 1000px; height: 500px;position:relative; top: 50px;left:20px;bottom:20px;right: 20px;background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/17.png');">
<br><br><center><strong>ADD AN ACTIVITY :: </strong></center>
<table>
<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ASSIGNED BY : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="assignedbyid" >
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="assignedbyid">Enter Name</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px" ><b>ASSIGNED TO : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="assignedtoid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="assignedtoid">Enter Name</span></td></tr>

<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ACTIVITY ID : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="activityidid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="activityidid">Enter ID</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ENVIRONMENT : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="envnameid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="envnameid">Enter Name</span></td></tr>

<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ENVIRONMENT ID : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="envidid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="envidid">Enter ID</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>STATUS : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="statusid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="statusid">Enter Status</span></td></tr>

<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ACTIVITY TYPE : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="activitytypeid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="activitytypeid">Enter Type</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ASSIGNED DATE : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" id="assigneddateid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="assigneddateid">Enter date</span></td></tr> 


<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ASSIGNED TIME : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox" id="assignedtimeid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="assignedtimeid">Enter time</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>SCHEDULED DATE : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" id="scheduleddateid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="scheduleddateid">Enter Date</span></td></tr>


<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>SCHEDULED TIME : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox" id="scheduledtimeid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="scheduledtimeid">Enter Time</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>PERCENT COMPLETE : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.NumberSpinner" id="percentcompleteid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="percentcompleteid">Enter Percentage</span></td></tr>


<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>DESCRIPTION : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="descriptionid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="descriptionid">Description</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>COMMENTS : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="commentsid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="commentsid">Enter Comments</span></td></tr>
</table>

<button id="submitbutton" type="submit" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"></button>
</div>
</center>
</div>     
</div>

    <!-- content panes: title is tab name, no special features here -->


<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Pending Activities" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/17.png');" preload="true">
<center><p><strong>LIST OF PENDING ACTIVITIES</strong></p></center>

<center><div id="gridDiv" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" title="Simple Grid" style="width:900px; height:200px;" preload="true">
</div></center>
<div class="dijitHidden">
    <div  id="terms" data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" style="width:900px; height: 500px;overflow: scroll; background: gray;" data-dojo-props="title:'Control Activities'" preload="true">
        <center><p><strong>EDIT AN ACTIVITY :: </strong></p></center>
        <center><table>
<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ASSIGNED BY : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="assignedbyid" >
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="assignedbyid">Enter Name</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px" ><b>ASSIGNED TO : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="assignedtoid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="assignedtoid">Enter Name</span></td></tr>

<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ACTIVITY ID : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="activityidid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="activityidid">Enter ID</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ENVIRONMENT : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="envnameid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="envnameid">Enter Name</span></td></tr>

<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ENVIRONMENT ID : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="envidid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="envidid">Enter ID</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>STATUS : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="statusid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="statusid">Enter Status</span></td></tr>

<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ACTIVITY TYPE : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="activitytypeid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="activitytypeid">Enter Type</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ASSIGNED DATE : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" id="assigneddateid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="assigneddateid">Enter date</span></td></tr> 


<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ASSIGNED TIME : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox" id="assignedtimeid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="assignedtimeid">Enter time</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>SCHEDULED DATE : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" id="scheduleddateid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="scheduleddateid">Enter Date</span></td></tr>


<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>SCHEDULED TIME : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox" id="scheduledtimeid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="scheduledtimeid">Enter Time</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>PERCENT COMPLETE : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.NumberSpinner" id="percentcompleteid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="percentcompleteid">Enter Percentage</span></td></tr>


<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>DESCRIPTION : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="descriptionid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="descriptionid">Description</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>COMMENTS : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="commentsid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="commentsid">Enter Comments</span></td></tr>



 <tr style="height: 50px">
       <td style="width: 600px"><button>START</button></td>
       <td style="width: 600px"><button>STOP</button></td>
       <td style="width: 600px"><button>HOLD</button></td>
       <td style="width: 600px"><button>CANCEL</button></td>
       <td style="width: 600px"><button>CLOSE</button></td></tr>

</table></center>


</div>
</div>

    </div>

    <!-- content panes: title is tab name, make this tab closable -->
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Filter an Activity" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/18.png');" preload="true">

      <center><div style="border-color:black; width: 1000px; height: 500px;position:relative; top: 50px;left:20px;bottom:50px;right: 20px;background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/17.png');">
      <br><br><p><strong>ENTER THE SEARCH CRITERIA :: </strong></p>
      <table>
<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>ASSIGNED BY : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="fassignedbyid" >
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="fassignedbyid">Enter Name</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px" ><b>PRODUCT : </b></td>
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="fproductid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="fproductid">Enter product</span></td></tr>

<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px"><b>STATUS : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="fstatusid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="fstatusid">Enter Status</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px"><b>START DATE : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" id="fstartdateid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="fstartdateid">Enter Date</span></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 100px"><b>STOP DATE : </b></td> 
<td style="width: 600px"><input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" id="fstopdateid">
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="fstopdateid">Enter date</span></td></tr>
</table>      
</div></center>


    </div>

    <!-- content panes: title is tab name, load content remotely, preload -->
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="SomeBand" href="some-page.html" preload="true">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the datagrid programmatically, you do not need to specify it in the declaration.

So, change:

```
<div id="gridDiv" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" title="Simple Grid" style="width:900px; height:200px;" preload="true">
```

to

```
<div id="gridDiv">
</div>
```

Also, change your datagrid population code to:

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        style: "height: 350px;width:500px;",
        store: store,
        structure: gridStructure,
        rowSelector: '30px',
        selectionMode: "single",
        autoHeight:true},
      'gridDiv');
```

You are using the preload option on the contentpane so you are right in expecting it to preload the datagrid :-)

However, with the above change if the grid still does not show up, it appears that since the DOM node gridDiv is set to display:none, the dojo datagrid is not able to render (since i guess it needs to calculate the available height, size etc for the gridDiv element to position the datagrid)

One way to solve this is to create an onShow event handler on the "pending activities" content pane:

1) give an id to the pending activities content pane:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="pending_activities" title="Pending Activities" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/17.png');" preload="true">
```

2) add the onShow event handler:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("pending_activities"), "onShow", function () {

  if (dijit.byId('grid') != null) {
     //populate the datagrid here
  }
});
```